# Elementor stuck on loading when adding JS code

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I added the following code in a .js file to change a word every 2 seconds on my home page and it works well on the live site:

```
var words = ["Word 1","Word 2"];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);
jQuery(function () {    
    i = 0;
    setInterval(function(){ $('#change_title_text').fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).html(words[(i = (i + 1) % words.length)]).fadeIn();
      }); }, 2000)
});
```

The script is enqueued in my child theme as usual:

```
function custom_js_script_enqueue(){
    wp_enqueue_script('mycustomjs', CHILD_THEME_URI . '/assets/js/my-custom-js.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_js_script_enqueue');
```

However, when I try to go to Pages in the WP Admin area and then press "Edit with Elementor" it opens up a window with the E loading screen and stucks there forever. It doesn't matter which page I try to load, it stucks on all pages. When commenting the code in the .js file I can edit with Elementor as usual.

I narrowed it down that it has something to do with these lines, since removing them makes Elementor load:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

What makes this cause an issue with loading elementor? Is there another way of loading a src that is compatible, or any other way of using the FadeIn/FadeOut?

Comment: you don't need to add/load another jquery on the page, WordPress already uses/loads jQuery on every backend and frontend page. If you'll load another Jquery then it will create conflicts and you'll start seeing issues as you're already seeing one.
And in your enqueue script code you have an empty array of dependencies `array()` you need to add jquery as dependencies using `array( 'jquery' )` in place of `array()`

Comment: @VijayHardaha, thank you, I am newbie Javascript coder :) So I just remove the word jQuery from the script after I have added it to enqueue?

Comment: @VijayHardaha, adding it to the wp_enqueue_script and deleting it from the script didn't work. The code don't run anymore on the page. I got many jQuery in the script since before, for example jQuery(window).on('scroll', function(){

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by **many jQuery** but you might be getting the `$` is undefined error in the console after removing the code that was adding another jQuery script. you solved undefined error by replacing `jQuery(function () { ` with `jQuery(function ($) {`

Comment: @VijayHardaha, I have more jQuery in the same file, e.g. jQuery(window).on('scroll', function(){ above, and in that function I have jQuery('.classname').addClass('active'); . Is this wrong?